# How to correctly instantiate a PixelBuffer for VLCJ mediaPlayer

Tags: java, javafx, vlc, vlcj

I am currently having issues getting VLCJ 4 to spin up a video. I can get the application to run, but seem to running into an issue with the `videoPixelBuffer` not being instantiated. The below code is from the pixelbuffer tutorial on the main page. I have been trying to understand how it is function but cannot see how the function that instantiates the `videoPixelBuffer` is ever called. I have tried to manually call it up that has not work either. I believe the issue is with `videoPixelBuffer`, but cannot see a way to fix this.

Any ideas?

Below you will see the code I am using and the error messages I have gotten.
Here is the link to the Github repo for the demo as well. (https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-javafx/blob/pixelbuffer-test/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/javafx/test/WritableImageDemo.java)

Versions:

- VLCJ 4.1.0
- VLC 3.0.8
- Openjdk 13
- Openjfx 13

Code:

```
package player;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelBuffer;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelFormat;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.factory.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.base.MediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.CallbackVideoSurface;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.VideoSurfaceAdapters;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.callback.BufferFormat;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.callback.BufferFormatCallback;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.callback.RenderCallback;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.callback.format.RV32BufferFormat;

public class Test extends Application {

    private MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory;

    private EmbeddedMediaPlayer embeddedMediaPlayer;

    private WritableImage videoImage;

    private PixelBuffer<ByteBuffer> videoPixelBuffer;

    private ImageView videoImageView;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        embeddedMediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.mediaPlayers().newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
        embeddedMediaPlayer.videoSurface().set(new FXCallbackVideoSurface());
    }

    @Override
    public final void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        videoImageView = new ImageView();
        videoImageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        videoImageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());
        videoImageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(root.heightProperty());
        root.getChildren().add(videoImageView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 675);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        String mrl = getParameters().getRaw().get(0);

        embeddedMediaPlayer.media().play(mrl);
    }

    @Override
    public final void stop() throws Exception {
        embeddedMediaPlayer.controls().stop();
        embeddedMediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayerFactory.release();
    }

    private class FXCallbackVideoSurface extends CallbackVideoSurface {
        FXCallbackVideoSurface() {
            super(new FXBufferFormatCallback(), new FXRenderCallback(), true, VideoSurfaceAdapters.getVideoSurfaceAdapter());
        }
    }

    private class FXBufferFormatCallback implements BufferFormatCallback {
        private int sourceWidth;
        private int sourceHeight;

        @Override
        public BufferFormat getBufferFormat(int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight) {
            this.sourceWidth = sourceWidth;
            this.sourceHeight = sourceHeight;
            return new RV32BufferFormat(sourceWidth, sourceHeight);
        }

        public void allocatedBuffers(ByteBuffer[] buffers) {
            assert buffers[0].capacity() == sourceWidth * sourceHeight * 4;
            PixelFormat<ByteBuffer> pixelFormat = PixelFormat.getByteBgraPreInstance();
            videoPixelBuffer = new PixelBuffer<>(sourceWidth, sourceHeight, buffers[0], pixelFormat);
            videoImage = new WritableImage(videoPixelBuffer);
            videoImageView.setImage(videoImage);
        }
    }

    private class FXRenderCallback implements RenderCallback {
        @Override
        public void display(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, ByteBuffer[] nativeBuffers, BufferFormat bufferFormat) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                videoPixelBuffer.updateBuffer(pb -> null);
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class WritableImageDemoLauncher {public static void main(String[] args) {Test.main(args);}}
```

Error Messages:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at player.Test$FXRenderCallback.lambda$0(Test.java:110)
at javafx.graphix/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AcessController.java:391)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:92)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop(WinApplication.java:174)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Test.java:110 is the following line:
`videoPixelBuffer.updateBuffer(pb -> null);`

Comment: If that is indeed the line that yields the NPE, `videoPixelBuffer` is `null`. This may be caused by the method of your anonymus class not being invoked or by the fact that the synchronisation is not doen properly potentially causing the application thread to never see an updated value for that field; java is allowed to create a seperate copy of data for every thread, unless you tell it specifically not to do that...

Comment: On which platform did you try this and does the original, unmodified example work for you? The code in question is part of the callbacks which are provided to the player and the player should call them when necessary.

Comment: The code you posted works for me (on Linux). I can't see why it would fail tbh. I don't see a line 110 when I paste your code into an editor.

Comment: I am working on windows, but could possibly port this over to a Linux environment.

Comment: Also I found some what of a work around. By putting the following: ```new FXBufferFormatCallback().allocatedBuffers(nativeBuffers);``` inside the ```Platform.runLater(() -> {}``` function. I am able to get the video to display, but the video is terrible quality.

Comment: At the time of writing the code, there were know problems with the Windows version of VLC. I don't know whether they have been fixed in the mean time.